# Use Rails benchmark in Cells

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-cells

I want use Rails own controller benchmarking method in Cells. I tried `include ActiveSupport::Benchmarkable` in the cells controller. However calling `self.class.benchmark` gives "no method exists" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I can call `self.benchmark` instead (instance method), which is different to Rails [where it is a class method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html#controller).